# how to search in Active Directory with LIKE?

Tags: ajax, search, active-directory, jquery-autocomplete

I have autoComplate Textbox. I need Fill that with samAccountName from AD using Ajax and use LIKE when search in AD.

this is my code but I have error:

```
 List<string> result = new List<string>();
    DirectoryEntry domain1 = default(DirectoryEntry);
    DirectorySearcher searcher = default(DirectorySearcher);
    domain1 = new DirectoryEntry();
    searcher = new DirectorySearcher("(&(samAccountType=805306368)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(samAccountName LIKE N'%" + username + "%'))");
    searcher.SearchRoot = domain1;
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    DataTable dtfill = new DataTable();
    dtfill.Columns.Add("UserName");

    using (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection userlist = searcher.FindAll())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= userlist.Count - 1; i++)
result.Add(Convert.ToString(userlist[i].GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samAccountName"].Value).ToLower());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searcher = new DirectorySearcher(string.Format("(&(samAccountType=805306368)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(samAccountName=*{0}*))", username));
```

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page provides a short overview for the syntax for searches.